# Arabic date conversion issue in java

Tags: java, spring

I have a bean class like

```
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Form {
    private String name;
    private Long numID;
    private String Address;
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    private LocalDate date1;

    // getters and setters

}
```

This is used in a rest controller class

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


public class MyController {

    private String MY_URL = "/model.do"
    @RequestMapping(value = {MY_URL}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    Public Model getModelType(@ModelAttribute Form myForm){

    }


}
```

now when I pass a arabic date object which is encoded like

%D9%A2%D9%A0%D9%A1%D9%A9-%D9%A0%D9%A4-%D9%A1%D9%A5, the conversion is failing with the below error

org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'form' on field 'date1': rejected value [????-??-??]; codes [typeMismatch.form.date1,typeMismatch.isoCheckInDate,typeMismatch.java.time.LocalDate,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [form.isoCheckInDate,isoCheckInDate]; arguments []; default message [isoCheckInDate]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate' for property 'date1'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.LocalDate] for value '????-??-??'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [????-??-??]]

Any idea how can to handle this type of scenario ?

Comment: Probably need UTF-16

Comment: The (unencoded) date is ٢٠١٩-٠٤-١٥ (2019-04-15).

Comment: Can you show us your code? [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: You pass the arabic date (is it today?) as an utf8 encoded **byte** string. The error probably comes from the fact that you fail to correctly convert it to a (unicode) Java String. Without knowing more (where does the date comes from and how) I cannot say more.

Comment: @OleV.V. added more code

Answer (score 2):

While I don’t know what Spring Framework has done and why, I *can* show you how to parse your string in plain Java:

```
    DecimalStyle defaultDecimalStyle
            = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.getDecimalStyle();
    DateTimeFormatter arabicDateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE
            .withDecimalStyle(defaultDecimalStyle.withZeroDigit('\u0660'));

    String encodedArabicDateStr = "%D9%A2%D9%A0%D9%A1%D9%A9-%D9%A0%D9%A4-%D9%A1%D9%A5";
    String arabicDateStr
            = URLDecoder.decode(encodedArabicDateStr, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(arabicDateStr, arabicDateFormatter);
    System.out.println("Parsed date: " + date);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> Parsed date: 2019-04-15

The only trick is to tell the formatter to parse Arabic digits. When we tell it the zero digit (`٠` or `'\u0660'`), it figures out the other digits.

Comment: I can't have a method like this, as the conversion is taken care by Spring automatically. Its happening after upgrading from jdk1.8 to 1.11.

Comment: It’s interesting that this happened when upgrading to Java 11. You may want to add this information in your question. Did you upgrade Spring Framework too (asking without knowing whether that was necessary)?

Comment: nope there was no Spring upgradation. I think its related to 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/intl/internationalization-enhancements-jdk-9.htm#JSINT-GUID-AF5AECA7-07C1-4E7D-BC10-BC7E73DC6C7F
I also tried passing 
java.locale.providers=COMPAT,SPI
which don't have any effect

Comment: I don’t readily see the connection to CLDR, and your attempt with `COMPAT,SPI` also to me confirms that it’s unrelated. Don’t know what it is, then, though.